# Are there any bash-scriptable tool for simple SQL operations?

Tags: sql, bash, shell

I have a quite big shell script that process data and output to bash arrays. I want to insert these output into PostgreSQL, but doing it in bash means I need to manually escape the strings, construct SQL statements, and piping SQL statements to psql, which is kind of error prone and ugly to code. Are there any SQL tools that is more shell-script-friendly? For example, a command line tool like

```
sql_insert my_sql_table 'value_1' 'value_2' 'value_3'
```

would be perfect. Or something that accept CSV format from a pipe will also be okay.

Of course I can easily write a Python script which does it, but I am just wondering if there are some existing tools for this.

Comment: Try `here-doc`...

Comment: Does Python count as a shell?

Comment: @GillesQuenot Here-docs are nice but I haven't figured out how to avoid escaping strings manually with here-doc yet.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, kind of... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
psql -U DB <<'EOF'
INSERT INTO foobar VALUES('foo', 'bar', 'base');
EOF
```

Not tested, maybe you have to adapt a bit, it's just for the idea

Comment: I'm also thinking about this but my difficulty is that I'm actually having `$FOO` and `$BAR` instead of `'foo'` and `'bar'`, and the `$FOO` variable can contain all kind of weird characters and even SQL injection...

Comment: With my syntax, $FOO will not be expanded because of the single quotes around `EOF`, no some backticks

Comment: note: `'foobar'` should **not** be in quotes. And $SHELL variables will be expanded in HERE-documents, even in single quotes.

Comment: No, check this https://gist.github.com/sputnick-dev/7c732e972592f73e2b8fae984f171ee0

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/sh

DB_NAME="omg"
SCHEMA_NAME="tmp"
TABLE_NAME="omg"
COLUMN_NAME="foobar"
COLUMN_VALUE="wtf"
psql -U postgres ${DB_NAME} <<OMG
SET search_path=${SCHEMA_NAME};

DROP TABLE "${TABLE_NAME}";
CREATE TABLE "${TABLE_NAME}"
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , ${COLUMN_NAME} text
         );
   -- single quotes here-------------------------------v---------------V
INSERT INTO "${TABLE_NAME}" ( ${COLUMN_NAME} )VALUES ( '${COLUMN_VALUE}' );

SELECT*FROM ${TABLE_NAME};
OMG
```

---

OUTPUT:

---

```
SET
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
 id | foobar 
----+--------
  1 | wtf
(1 row)
```

Comment: Building a SQL query using string interpolation is a very bad idea unless you know exactly what the values of the variables are, in which case you may as well not use variables in the first place.

Comment: What is "string interpolation" ? Are you aiming at SQL-injection?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am warning against. The  term "string interpolation" probably applies more to languages where quotes are the syntax for defining a string literal, whereas in shell the quotes just perform bulk quoting on a set of characters.

Comment: Then:please say so. And: the question was about embedding SQL in a shell script. Using prepared statement is trivial. And orthogonal to the OQ.